# In the United States, if there were no speed limit on the loop, how fast would you go? At what speed would you get ticketed?

Tags: united-states, traffic, driving

Legally speaking, how fast should you go on a loop without speed limit? At what speed would you get ticketed?  I am not looking for an answer like " Just go at a safe speed."

Comment: (1) What's a "loop"?  (2) Traffic laws in the US are state-by-state, not federal, so please specify a state in order to get an answer (and add an appropriate tag).  (3) I believe most, if not all, states have a statewide default speed limit, as well as a general law requiring that you drive at a speed which is reasonable / prudent / safe for conditions.  In the latter case, obviously there is no set speed and it is case-by-case; to convict you, the state would have to convince a judge / jury that your speed was not reasonable / prudent / safe.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "Just go the safe speed, or the posted speed, depending on the state". The majority of states have absolute limits, so if the road is posted for 60 or the road class is stated as being 60, it is 60 and you cannot go faster. Some states have a "presumed" speed limit (Texas and California for example). You might be driving at 45 in a 40 in California and legally get away with it, if it is safe. There is a prima facie limit spelled out in [Veh. Code 22352](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=22352.&lawCode=VEH) – 15 in an alley, 20 in a school crossing; and whatever the sign says. But then you are not in violation if

> the defendant establishes by competent evidence that the speed in
>   excess of said limits did not constitute a violation of the [basic
>   speed law](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=22350.) at the time, place and under the conditions then existing

(where the basic law is that you may not "drive a vehicle upon a highway at a speed greater than is reasonable or prudent having due regard for weather, visibility, the traffic on, and the surface and width of, the highway, and in no event at a speed which endangers the safety of persons or property"). That means you have to convince the court that it was safe. There are, also, absolute limits (such as on freeways: or anything over 100 mph, even that stretch outside Needles).

[Texas Transportation Code Section 545.352](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/docs/TN/htm/TN.545.htm) likewise has flexibility, where 30 in urban streets is lawful, and

> A speed in excess of the limits established by Subsection (b) or under
>   another provision of this subchapter is prima facie evidence that the
>   speed is not reasonable and prudent and that the speed is unlawful

but you can argue that the speed was factually safe.